# Как удобнее задать стили

Tags: html, css

Имеются секции с чередующимся цветом фона и текста, как удобнее задать стили, чтобы не прописывать их для каждой секции.

Есть класс с общими стилями секций, у меня из вариантов только добавить к нечетным секциям еще один класс который будет задавать цвет фона и текста.

Есть еще какие нибудь предложения или варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как вариант:**

Используйте псевдокласс `:nth-child`. [Подробнее...](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)
[Подробнее о поддержке в разных браузерах...](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child)

```css
.block > .row >.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
}
.block > .row >.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #000;
}

.block > .row-o >.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;
}

.block > .row-o >.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-o">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-o">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD**

```css
.container {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper > section:nth-child(even) > .container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <section>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: `:nth-child(2n)` или `:nth-child(2n + 1)` будут работать в 97% браузеров, начиная с IE9

Comment: @andreymal, это хорошо, что-то я не туда глянул :)

Comment: Спасибо) данный вариант тоже рассматривал, но была проблема со структурой и как-то не корректно работало, сейчас поправил все хорошо. Но почему-то не хочет меняться цвет шрифта, видимо он где-то дальше переназначается или специфичность выше, хотя даже при добавлении !important ни чего не меняется. Ладно буду разбираться дальше)

Comment: @Cactus, появился еще небольшой вопрос, если у меня вот такая структура
<div class="wrapper">
   <section>
     <div class="container"> </div>
   </section>
   <section>
     <div class="container"> </div>
   </section>
   <section>
     <div class="container"> </div>
   </section>
</div>
и нужно задать бекграунд для контейнера, то уже так не получится?

Comment: @kost1k, вроде получилось:) Обновил ответ. А если в предыдущем комментарии вы говорили, что не получается сменить цвет, то попробуйте `ctrl`  + `f5` в хроме. Обновите кэш, иногда помогает:)